# Splitting an overlong IIncludableQueryable<>

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a fairly complex data model with some 30-odd tables. I'm working on a Web API to provide data to an Angular 2 front-end, and found that it would be easiest to download a "whole" item with all its subclasses in one go, considering that this doesn't involve much data.

However, I'm now looking at the following monstrosity:

```
var query = context.GlobalBcf
    .Include(x => x.Location)
    .Include(x => x.RadioEquipment.Model)
    .Include(x => x.RadioEquipment.RadioEquipmentSuppliers).ThenInclude(x => x.Supplier)
    .Include(x => x.RadioEquipment.RadioEquipmentTypes).ThenInclude(x => x.Type)
    .Include(x => x.GlobalBcfPowerSupplies).ThenInclude(x => x.PowerSupply)
    .Include(x => x.GlobalBcfApplications).ThenInclude(x => x.Application)
    .Include(x => x.OvtpType)
    .Include(x => x.BatteryType)
    .Include(x => x.AmountBattery)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.Mode)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.TrxSigBw1)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.TrxSigBw2)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.TrxSigBw3)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.TrxSigBw4)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment).ThenInclude(x => x.Btses)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.ExternalComponent)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.Repeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.Type)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.Repeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.FrequenceRepeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.Model)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.Repeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.FrequenceRepeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.Supplier)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.Repeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.MasterUnits).ThenInclude(x => x.Model)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.Repeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.MasterUnits).ThenInclude(x => x.PowerSupply)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.Repeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.MasterUnits).ThenInclude(x => x.Supplier)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.Repeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.MasterUnits).ThenInclude(x => x.OpticRepeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.OtrxModel)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.Repeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.MasterUnits).ThenInclude(x => x.OpticRepeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.RuModel)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.Repeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.MasterUnits).ThenInclude(x => x.OpticRepeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.RuPowerSupply)
    .Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.Repeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.MasterUnits).ThenInclude(x => x.OpticRepeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.RuMode)
    .AsQueryable();

return query.Single(x => x.Id == message.Id);
```

This is obviously becoming hard to maintain, so I'm wondering whether it wouldn't be possible to split this up into smaller, easier to maintain pieces which don't repeat the same over and over:

- `.Include(x => x.Bcfs)`
- `.Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments)`
- `.Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.Repeaters)`
- `.Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.Repeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.MasterUnits)`
- `.Include(x => x.Bcfs).ThenInclude(x => x.BcfSegments).ThenInclude(x => x.Segment.Repeaters).ThenInclude(x => x.MasterUnits).ThenInclude(x => x.OpticRepeaters)`.

Any tips, pointers, ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution by just splitting pieces of code into different extension:

```
class SupraBigZone {
    public List<Zone> Zones {get; set;}
}

class Zone {
    public SupraBigZone SupraBigZone {get; set;}
    public List<SmallZone> SmallZones {get; set;}
}

class SmallZone {
    public Zone Zone {get; set;}
}
```

And then you have a class containing a SupraBigZone:

```
class Game {
    public SupraBigZone GameZone {get; set;}

    public OtherProperty OtherProperty {get; set;}
}

public static class IQueryableExtensions
{
    public static IIncludableQueryable<T, Zone> IncludeSupraBigZone<T>(this IQueryable<T> values, Func<T,SupraBigZone> getSupraBigZone) where T : class
    {
        return values
            .Include(c => getSupraBigZone(c)).ThenInclude(h => h.Zones).ThenInclude(z => z.SupraBigZone)
            .Include(c => getSupraBigZone(c)).ThenInclude(h => h.Zones).ThenInclude(z => z.SmallZones).ThenInclude(s => s.Zone);
    }
}
```

Note that the extension takes Zone as second generic type, this is because in this example, the very last include includes a Zone.

In your DbContext, you can use it as follows:

```
public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }

public IQueryable<Car> GameWithDependencies
{
    get
    {
        return
            Games
            .IncludeSupraBigZone(g => g.GameZone)
            .Include(g => g.OtherProperty);
    }
}
```